# Is there an API to add, remove & delete notes for Microsoft Sticky Notes?

Tags: python, windows

I am using [Microsoft Sticky Notes](https://www.microsoft.com/store/productId/9NBLGGH4QGHW) and I want to create a script that can sync these sticky notes with my Google Keep notes although I haven't found any way to do this programmatically and I'm not sure if this is even possible especially as it is a UWP app.

Comment: what troubles are you facing exactly? if you can find where the notes are stored, then a simple script to copy that data and use some google api (definitely google has sth) to upload the copied data shouldn't be too hard to write

Comment: @Matiiss I haven't really found any information (at least for recent version of sticky notes) and I haven't been able to find where the notes are stored, how the data is stored etc. All the files I have found are encoded in some way I am unable to deduce.

Comment: well, if there is no API, no easy way to get the data, no built-in converter in the app that could help with this or any of that stuff, then really there are only impractical solutions (possible but really impractical, such as maybe taking screenshots of those notes and uploading those to google or using sth like `pyautogui` to go around and copy-paste the text if that is possible from the notes themselves) or just don't use the app, just use `google keep` all the time and when not available, just write to notepad and later copy paste from there, considering that you wouldn't do it too often

Answer (score -1):

Yes, there is one
Please refere to the answer above or this link (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/integrate-with-onenote) for more information

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Whoever left this comment in a review: There is **nothing** unclear about this proposed answer. The question is: *"Does Xyz exist?"*, and "*Xyz does not exist"* is about as clear as it gets.

Answer (score -1):

Currently, there is no Microsoft API to list sticky notes. OneNote notebooks? Yes. Sticky Notes? No.

<s>**Yes there is.**  Sticky Notes is part of Microsoft OneNote. ( https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sticky_Notes )</s>

Information about the API is here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/integrate-with-onenote

You can also access your sticky notes online by going to the following page:
https://onenote.com/stickynotes